# Does the Domain attribute affect SameSite on an http cookie?

Tags: rest, cookies, cross-domain, httpcookie

Will a CORS request set/send a cookie with `SameSite=Strict` if the cookie's domain attribute is set to the client's domain?

For example, if I make a request from `cors.com` to `cors-api.com`, will this configuration allow my cookie to be set and sent?

```
Set-Cookie: MY_KEY=<MY_VALUE>; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=cors.com; SameSite=Strict;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot set a `Domain` value that does not match the site setting the cookie - the browser should reject this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Invalid_domains

The `Domain` is used to control if the cookie will be sent for subdomains of the originating site.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies

If you need cookies to be sent in a cross-site context, they must be set with `SameSite=None; Secure`.